# Edge more attractive and beautiful without using CSS3

Tags: html, css, layout, border

I am developing a site, you can see the code in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/8/) link.
I put a gray border on it but would like to put a border more attractive and beautiful.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without CSS3? Use images or image sprites